# Where is Android bug tracker? (other than Android Google Code project)

Tags: android

For working around a problem on Android I've reached to [this diff](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ed4f28b492da3ff140bbaabbbda798a08c40ea5b%5E!/). The bug id (Bug 2936741) is not available on [Google Code bug tracker of Android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2936741), so where is the Android Bug tracker that this diff indicating to?

Comment: It seems that it has been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android bugs with very high numbers are probably in Google's internal bug tracking system. usually if it's a publicly-reported AOSP bug, we'll paste the actual *link* to that bug tracker (because the internal systems will automatically link to the internal bug tracker, we only need to give the number for those).