# What does area Area: BUG means in commit message in google git for android?

Tags: android

I noticed a field `Bug: XXXX` in [android's commit messages](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4cfe29b.).

What does this field indicate? Is it Google's way to track issues?
Where can I find the issue details from this bug id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `Bug` field in a commit's message indicates to which bug this commit is related.

There is the [AOSP bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list), but it does not contain *all* the bugs.
In your case, the bug is probably on an internal list.

- See also: [Where is Android bug tracker? (other than Android Google Code project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263912/where-is-android-bug-tracker-other-than-android-google-code-project)